# Ignore Hibernate READONLY cache in unit testing

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm running into issues unit testing a Hibernate entity with a READ_ONLY cache setting. I need to create new ones during unit testing.

I get the error: Can't write to a readonly object

I've been trying to find a way to disable this cache setting in unit testing.

I was hoping to interact with the meta model but I don't know which property to set to disable caching for this entity or if it's even possible.

Setting the cache on a session level doesn't work because the object hasn't been created yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selective caching of entities can be achieved via 'shared-cache-mode' element in persistence.xml

ENABLE_SELECTIVE : Entities are not cached unless you explicitly mark them as cachable. 
This is the default and recommended value.

DISABLE_SELECTIVE : Entities are cached unless you explicitly mark them as not cacheable.

read more [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#shared-cache-mode-values)